# Send data (in push) between different classes in C#

Tags: c#, push-notification, observer-pattern

I have two classes A and B. Class A create a SerialPort and received data from device (so event-based). Now I want send this data to class B, and I know only one possibility: Observer Pattern. Please advice me

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I would like some advice on what pattern to use for this scenario

Answer (score 2):

I think you're on the right track leveraging the Observer Patter, you may also want to check out the Publish-Subscribe strategy http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern